# Mixing different version of the same library in flex

Tags: apache-flex, papervision3d

How can I use two version of a library in the same project in Flex (using Eclipse).
(in my case the library is papervision3d , and I have written some code using the older version, but due to big changes many of the used function exist no more)

thx

Answer (score 1):

Well the best would be to rewrite your old code to use the new library. But Papervision3d gives you the source So change the namespace and point to the new Namespace when writing your new code. The only real downside besides added complexity is that you'll have to spell out your variable declarations if you use both versions in the same class.